# Share button (feed) with Direct URL opens entire facebook page

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps, facebook-iframe, facebook-sharer

I am implementing a share button on my facebook app ( I don't wanna use Like )
And i am using this url for it :

```
  http://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?
  app_id=123050457758183&
  link=http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/&
  picture=http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg&
  name=Facebook%20Dialogs&
  caption=Reference%20Documentation&
  description=Using%20Dialogs%20to%20interact%20with%20users.&
  message=Facebook%20Dialogs%20are%20so%20easy!&
  redirect_uri=http://www.example.com/response
```

I got it from [This Documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/)

Now when i do press the link, everything works fine but it opens the share option in a whole facebook frame instead of just the share option.
Meaning i get the chat and sidebar and header etc.

Anyone knows how can i get rid of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok. Solved it, was too hasty to publish question sorry.

Found the answer [Here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/)

the feed dialog has a "display" property which i set to "popup".

Will mark as solved ASAP.

Thanks and hope this helps anyone